# 'presimplification' of GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, topojson

As you know, `topojson.presimplify` adds a `z` value to each of the coordinates to demonstrate its significance at certain zoom levels, so that the renderer isn't wasting time rendering points that the human eye isn't likely to see anyways.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7755778

I have some topojson I've loaded into the browser. Problem is: I need to parse that TopoJSON (which converts it to GeoJSON) before rendering and so that I can apply an algorithm to make some manipulations which adds some interpolated coordinates. This makes `topojson.presimplify` impossible. And even if I presimplify it before parsing the features, they are lost after my manipulations (because of the new data points).

Since `topojson.presimplify` uses its shared arcs system to determine the z value, I can't retro fit that code to work with GeoJSON. Is there any way to determine the Z value on GeoJSON data short of converting back to TopoJSON after manipulating it?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a late answer, but you can take a look at https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt and https://www.mapbox.com/blog/introducing-geojson-vt/ which filters and simplifies GeoJSON data on the fly.